# Custom drawable in sidebar not the right color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I've added a sidebar (navigation drawer) to my app that currently looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNpmt.png

However, the colors are wrong. The drawable image (`.png`) for the plus icon inside of the red circle should be white (as the image is), but it's being tinted blue and I'm not sure how to prevent this.

It appears to be blue because of the `textColorSecondary` value in my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/dark_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Here is the list items for the sidebar:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="Menu">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_48dp"
                    android:title="One"
                    android:checked="true"/>
                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
                    android:title="Two" />
                <item
                    android:icon="@drawable/custom_icon"
                    android:title="Three" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Here is the `custom_icon` drawable used in the third item in the list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/circle_icon">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#ff0000"
                />
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        />

</layer-list>
```

How can I prevent the color of the plus icon from being changed by the value of `textColorSecondary` and keep its original white color?

---

As an additional side question, how can I style the sidebar completely (including subheader text color, list item text color, etc)? I can't find any tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own question.

Simply do the following:

```
NavigationView sidebar = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.sidebar);
sidebar.setItemIconTintList(null);
```